# Host matching in Symfony3 routes

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations

I have a website (`example.com`) which has a subdomain for the customer area like `customer.example.com`. Now I want to add a different subdomain which is exactly the same as that website but only has a different images.
This should result in `example.com` equals `demo.example.com` and  `customer.exmaple.com` equals `customer.demo.example.com`.

At the moment I have the current route annotation bind to the class for the customer side:

```
/**
 * Customer links
 * @Route(host="customer.%domain%")
 */
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
```

(domain is defined in config.yml)

I tried changing that to match hosts like so:

```
/**
 * Customer links
 * @Route(
 *     host="customer.{domain}",
 *     defaults={"domain"="%domain%"},
 *     requirements={"domain"="%domain%|demo.%domain%"}
 * )
 */
```

But this won't work since you need to provide a default parameter for domain, and this will always be the value in this case. So the URL works, but every other link will redirect you back to `customer.domain.com`

I tried the same thing in routing.yml which had the same results.

Is it possible to have a dynamic domain/subdomain, and if so, how could I do it?

Comment: You can use security.yml files to make dynamic domain subdomain as well.

Comment: @Kapil I can't find anything about that. Do you perhaps have a link to a manual?